# Recieveing Cannot GET/ when executing yarn start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

I am new to react and yarn and followed a guide on how to set up a react application with Yarn and WebPack.
Guide: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-webpack-babel-b76545c6e353

I wanted to change the `webpack.config.js` to write the `bundle.js` file outside of the root folder when I run `yarn build`. But doing so breaks `yarn start` in a way where I receive `Cannot GET /` in my browser. I tracked down the problem to this line `path: __dirname + './../someFolder/someOtherFolder/` If I remove it, `yarn start` is no longer showing me the error.

Any idea what I can do? I want to keep building outside of my root folder while developing. This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './src/index.html',
    filename: './index.html'
})

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js|jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: { loader: 'babel-loader' }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 3030,
        open: true
    },
    plugins: [
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
    ],
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'pw_module.js',
        path: __dirname + './../someFolder/someOtherFolder/',
        publicPath: '/'
    }
};
```

This is the `"scripts":` Section from my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "test": "jest --colors -b -e --logHeapUsage",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
```

Comment: `filename: './index.html'` seems to be the wrong path. the error tells you that the requested page could not be found

Comment: Yeah I get a 404 on GET in the console of the browser. I have a feeling that it's looking for the index.html within the folder I have specified in output. Could that be?

Comment: imho you have to set an entry point to your webpack config. This should be a `.js` file. have a look here: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/

Comment: please give a feeback once you've tried it according to the docs link i posted. Also update your question with what you have tried :)

Comment: I tried that already but sadly it wont fix my problem, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.